# White space comes up with keyboard when clicking on input fields in Custom tab inside a Teams Personal app (Iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, microsoft-teams

We have created an App in Teams developer portal with a feature of "Personal App". We have filled in all the details, for example, content url, website url etc. The Iframe inside the app loads correctly in the browser and desktop versions. But we are facing some user interface issues when opening the app in mobile app.

When ever we click on the input fields, keyboard pops up with a white space attached on top of it. The white space usually disappears after the keyboard closes but there were instances where we see a white space on the bottom of the app after the keyboard is closed also. This is occurring mostly in  Android mobiles and sometimes in IOS too. I am attaching the screenshots of the issue. Please look into it. Please let us know what we can do to solve this issue.

Also, the white space doesn't come up if our website is loaded on a normal browser. So the problem is occurring only if we open the website as an iframe inside teams.
[Example of the white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThJW.png)

We have tried clearing cache, uninstalling the app and reinstalling it. But the issue doesn't seemed to be solved.

Example manifest.json file. Please sideload it in your desktop teams and view it in mobile. We can see the issue when clicked on input tags.

`{"$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.15/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json","version":"1.0.0","manifestVersion":"1.15","id":"a4de606e-5ec1-4ea4-93b3-579b9999a329","packageName":"com.package.name","name":{"short":"test","full":""},"developer":{"name":"test","mpnId":"","websiteUrl":"https://allwebco-templates.com/support/","privacyUrl":"https://allwebco-templates.com/support/","termsOfUseUrl":"https://allwebco-templates.com/support/"},"description":{"short":"qwerty","full":"asdfg"},"icons":{"outline":"outline.png","color":"color.png"},"accentColor":"#FFFFFF","staticTabs":[{"entityId":"84fbd37d-1759-4da9-96af-cc86fb98b3f0","name":"home","contentUrl":"https://allwebco-templates.com/support/","scopes":["personal"]},{"entityId":"about","scopes":["personal"]}],"validDomains":["allwebco-templates.com"],"isFullScreen":true,"defaultGroupCapability":{"team":"tab","groupchat":"tab","meetings":"tab"}}`

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to [share your code as text not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: @KargWare Thank you for the suggestion. The images I have uploaded are output images. Haven't shared any code yet.

Comment: Could you please share the manifest json,so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: Could you please share the manifest json,so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT please see the below manifest. Please sideload it and view in mobile. you can view the issue when clicking on search fields. Updated the manifest.json in description.

Comment: We are tried to repro the scenario, but not able to repro. It is not showing whitespace when I click on search. Teams Version-1416/1.0.0.2022395202/1027
Android Version-8.1.0
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6d4D.png

Comment: Thank you @Sayali-MSFT will check with the versions and get back.

Comment: Also, @Sayali-MSFT could you please confirm if we are using the correct version of manifest? i.e version 1.15.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT our teams android version is 1416/1.0.0.2022425002/1206. Could the issue be due to the version difference?

Comment: @Sai Sanjana Gudla -Yes, I am using the same manifest version.
Could you please update the android teams version and check it once?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT We don't have any update in our Teams work app. Could you please look into this.

Comment: @Sai Sanjana Gudla - We are again check the scenario with the latest update.
Could you please check it once, update is available on play store.
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjBUA.jpg
Teams version -  1416/1.0.0.2022434101/1218

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thank you so much, we got update today, and white space issue is resolved!